# SQL append in middle of column data in update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

When we do data refresh we need to append `\\prod01\\Test\Load` server name with `\\prod01.qa.com\\Test\Load`

How do I write update query for this. There can be different server names all I need to do is write update script to append server name with qa.com

This is my query that gives all results that have server location.

`select * from AppSetting where Value like '%\\%\%' or Value like '%//%/%';`

My Prod data looks like this

```
Value
\\prod01\Images\Load
\\prod01prod6253\Images\Load
\\server05ser\Images\Delete
\\pgdg1076\Email
\\pgdg1076ythg\Test\Load
http://prod7/delta/
```

My QA data should looks like this after update query

```
Value
\\prod01.qa.com\Images\Load
\\prod01prod6253.qa.com\Images\Load
\\server05ser.qa.com\Images\Delete
\\pgdg1076.qa.com\Email
\\pgdg1076ythg.qa.com\Test\Load
http://prod7.qa.com/delta/
```

This is the update query I have. Can I write a generic query

```
UPDATE eroom.AppSetting
SET Location = REPLACE(Location, '\\prod01\', '\\prod01.qa.tbc.com\') 
WHERE Location like '%\\prod01\%';
```

```
UPDATE eroom.AppSetting
SET Location = REPLACE(Location, '\\server05ser\', '\\server05ser.qa.tbc.com\') 
WHERE Location like '%\\server05ser\%';
```

Comment: You might look into the STUFF function.

Comment: Well, your latest edit moves the goal posts (significantly).

Comment: I accidentally added // before http sorry. If there is a value between \\THIS_IS-SERVER\ we can think it as server name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting this as a new answer, as the OP moved the goal posts quite a bit. Instead, I now use `CHARINDEX` to find the location of each slash (forward or back). As *fortunately* the injection needs to happen before the 3rd slash, we can use that to our advantage:

```
SELECT STUFF(V.Value,CI3.I,0,'.qa.tbc.com') AS NewValue,*
FROM (VALUES('\\prod01\Images\Load'),
            ('\\prod01prod6253\Images\Load'),
            ('\\server05ser\Images\Delete'),
            ('\\pgdg1076\Email'),
            ('\\pgdg1076ythg\Test\Load'),
            ('http://prod7/delta/'))V([value])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN V.[value] LIKE '%/%' THEN '/' ELSE '\' END)) L(C) --So I don't have to keep checking what character I need
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(L.C,V.[value]))) CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(L.C,V.[value],CI1.I+1))) CI2(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(L.C,V.[value],CI2.I+1))) CI3(I);
```

Comment: Great this select query works..How do I put this in my update query?```SELECT STUFF(V.Value,CI3.I,0,'.qa.tbc.com') AS NewValue,*
FROM (select SettingValue from eroom.AppSetting where SettingValue like '%\\%\%' or SettingValue like '%//%/%')V([value])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CASE WHEN V.[value] LIKE '%/%' THEN '/' ELSE '\' END)) L(C)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(L.C,V.[value]))) CI1(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(L.C,V.[value],CI1.I+1))) CI2(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(L.C,V.[value],CI2.I+1))) CI3(I);```

Comment: `UPDATE YT SET YourColumn = STUFF... FROM YourTable YT CROSS APPLY...` @Luci just like any other `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Thank you :-) you saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is one method. I put the expressions for the `PATINDEX` and `CHARINDEX` in the `FROM`, as I find it far easier to read, and means less repetition:

```
SELECT V.[value],
       ISNULL(STUFF(V.Value,ISNULL(CI.fs,CI.bs),0,'.qa.tbc.com'),V.[value]) AS NewValue
FROM (VALUES('\\prod01\Images\Load'),
            ('\\prod05\Images\Delete'),
            ('\\prod10\Email'),
            ('//http://prod7/delta/'))V([value])
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%prod[0-9]%',V.value),0)))PI(I)
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/',V.[value],PI.I),0),NULLIF(CHARINDEX('\',V.[value],PI.I),0))) CI(fs,bs);
```

Comment: prod is not the reliable suffix it can be prod1 or server1 or anything. It can only have this patter '%\\%\%'

Comment: I don't use `'prod'` @Luci I use `'prod[0-9]'` and what do you mean by `server1`? If you have *other* scenarios, why didn't you include those in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the original version of the question.

The simplest way might be with `stuff()` and a `case` expression:

```
select (case when location like '\\prod[0-9][0-9]\*'
             then stuff(location, 9, 0, '.qa.tbc.com'
             else location
        end)
```

The "prod" portion looks to be fixed length, so you don't need to search for a pattern.

Comment: @Larnu . . . The OP changed the question *after* I answered it, which I think is rather rude.

Comment: My comment was *before* they changed it @GordonLinoff (see my first answer with their original sample data). I too, was frustrated that they changed the ball park so much afterwards though.